# Can one prevent a node.js worker from exiting the main process

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-worker, worker, worker-thread

I am using nodejs 12 and this questions is related to https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html
I know that Workers are sharing the same process as the main JS "thread"; still I am wondering if there's a way to prevent any error in the worker code from crashing the main process.

I want to use a worker thread instead of forked process but this issue would be a blocker.

`worker.js`

```js
const { parentPort } = require( "worker_threads");

let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  parentPort.postMessage({ hello: "world" });
  i++;
  if (i > 5) {
    throw new Error('Hello'); // imagine here some error that hasn't been caught
  }
}, 200);

setInterval(() => {
  parentPort.postMessage({ foo: "bar" });
}, 600);
```

`index.js`

```js
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const worker = new Worker("./worker.js");

worker.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

worker.on("exit", () => {
  console.log('Worker exited')
});

worker.on("message", msg => {
  console.log(msg)
});
```

`Output`

```sh
➜ node index.js
{ hello: 'world' }
{ hello: 'world' }
{ foo: 'bar' }
{ hello: 'world' }
{ hello: 'world' }
{ hello: 'world' }
{ foo: 'bar' }
{ hello: 'world' }
Error: Something happened
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/micael/Desktop/crashing/worker.js:10:11)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
Worker exited
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Errors in the worker do not crash the main thread**. The reason your main process exits is because there are no more pending events for the event loop to process once the worker thread exits. This is the same as regular main scripts such as:

```
// index.js
console.log('hello');
// this scripts exits here
```

If you run the simple script above you will see node.js exit the main process at the end of the script. This is normal behavior.

To prove this give your main thread something else to do:

```
// index.js
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const worker = new Worker("./worker.js");

worker.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

worker.on("exit", () => {
  console.log('Worker exited')
});

worker.on("message", msg => {
  console.log(msg)
});

setInterval(() => console.log('main is running'), 500);
```

You will find the main thread continue to run after your worker thread crashes.

---

#### Additional answer

From your comment it appears that what you want is not for the main thread to continue running but for the worker thread to continue running. This is not possible by the nature of how javascript handles uncaught errors: the interpreter will simply log the error and exit. The interpreter exiting will cause the thread to terminate.

If you want the second `setTimeout` to continue after the worker thread dies you need to run it in a separate thread:

worker1.js:

```
const { parentPort } = require( "worker_threads");

let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  parentPort.postMessage({ hello: "world" });
  i++;
  if (i > 5) {
    throw new Error('Hello'); // imagine here some error that hasn't been caught
  }
}, 200);
```

worker2.js:

```
const { parentPort } = require( "worker_threads");

setInterval(() => {
  parentPort.postMessage({ foo: "bar" });
}, 600);
```

index.js:

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const worker1 = new Worker("./worker.js");
const worker2 = new Worker("./worker.js");

worker1.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

worker1.on("exit", () => {
  console.log('Worker exited')
});

worker1.on("message", msg => {
  console.log(msg)
});

worker2.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

worker2.on("exit", () => {
  console.log('Worker exited')
});

worker2.on("message", msg => {
  console.log(msg)
});
```

Alternatively you can run the second setInterval in the main thread:

worker.js:

```
const { parentPort } = require( "worker_threads");

let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  parentPort.postMessage({ hello: "world" });
  i++;
  if (i > 5) {
    throw new Error('Hello'); // imagine here some error that hasn't been caught
  }
}, 200);
```

index.js:

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const worker = new Worker("./worker.js");

worker.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

worker.on("exit", () => {
  console.log('Worker exited')
});

worker.on("message", msg => {
  console.log(msg)
});

setInterval(() => {
  parentPort.postMessage({ foo: "bar" });
}, 600);
```

Comment: I don't think it's correct, if I wrap the first set interval in a `try  .. catch`, then the second interval should keep the process running and yet... it doesn't

Comment: The process is running. I tried it on my machine. Try my modified index.js file

Comment: Do you mean the `setInterval` with `parentPort.postMessage({ foo: "bar" });` is not running? Of course it is not - the thread has crashed. You will see the same behavior if you use multiple separate node.js process instead of threads. But the main thread does not crash

Comment: I get your point now (in your first comment). So, that answers my question, thanks. But now I am also wondering, why catching the error (I added a try catch around the first setInterval in the worker.js) does not prevent the worker from crashing.

Comment: You're probably try..catching in the wrong place. I assume you `try { setInterval ..` when you should instead do `setInterval(() => { try { ...`

Comment: I just realized that if you use worker threads in this way - to isolate errors - javascript behaves kind of like Erlang where the normal way to handle errors is to simply let them happen and ignore them

Comment: You're correct the try catch was misplaced. However, I have another strange/funny use case now. The worker is loading a c++ addon that calls `std::abort()` and that crashes the entire process (both the worker and index.js). Even though I have a setInterval running in the index.js

Comment: Ah, then for that one you probably should write a separate script and simply `child_process.exec()` it. Normally you'd do this if you need to run a non-js program but in your case it also makes sense.

Comment: Remember that on Linux there's very little difference (almost zero performance difference) between a thread and a process - they are both implemented using the same code. You can start with a process and start disabling features and end up with a thread and you can start with a thread and start adding features and end up with a process. So if your server is Linux just run a process

Comment: Yes but afaik you can't speak binary (I essentially want to share buffers) between the main "thread" and the child process, right? Which you can with a worker thread

Comment: You sort of can with a socket - just use an appropriate protocol and serializer/deserializer. You can remove IP overhead by using a named pipe for the socket if you want

Comment: You can also try the various `mmap` modules on npm if you want shared memory